# Possible EEVEE playback downsampling to 1 sample turn off?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Love EEVEE. Actual working on realtime VJ videomapping project.

Is it possible in EEVEE to **turn off** **downsampling** to 1 sample when playback animation?

I know its working that to keep smooth/realtime framerate, but 1 sample is very noisy (when turn off Viewport Denosing is little, little better)

Even that I I would like to playback with more samples despite the costs of smooth playback (even 5fps)

Is there command line for that?

I have gtx1080ti and ryzen 7.